# Switch out a dll in a click once app?

Tags: clickonce, dll

I have a click-once app that, for certain reasons I cannot republish a new version. At the same time, I have a dll that will replace one of the existing dlls in the app. Is it possible to simply go into the Application Files folder and switch it out? The dlls in the click once seem to be in a different format, [file].dll.deploy. Can I convert a dll I have to this format somehow and let it replace the existing one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot just swap out the dll. ClickOnce generates a hash for every file being deployed. Even though the new file has the same name, it won't have the same hash contained in the manifest and won't work.

I would open your manifests in [MageUI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhctdw55%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and try to update them that way.

If you don't increment the version number, no one will get the new file unless they uninstall/reinstall. Is there a particular reason you can't just republish?

Answer (score 1):

I have been fighting with this for a couple of days, it can be done but it's fiddly, With this solution ClickOnce still scans all files and shows the progress bar but only downloads and updates the changes.

Here is the process I have written to apply this patching method...

Note this process need to be carried on with an exact copy of the Click once deployment to be upgraded.

In the Application Files folder…

1. open  .exe.manifest using mageui (version 3.5 or greater assuming VS2010)
2. Change the version number
3. Replace the patched file(s) Note: files are renamed with the filename .deploy E.g. Control.DLL becomes control.DLL.Deploy
4. Sign & Save the File with you PFX file

In the Root Path

1. Open  .application file  using mageui (version 3.5 or greater)
2. Change the version number
3. Change the minimum required version number
4. Select the exe.manifest modified above
5. Sign & Save the File

Copy .application to Application Files folder*
*Note:  This step is not strictly necessary, but just keeps the backup files relevant.*

Manifest files and patched libraries can now be copied to your deployment environment.